# Allow only Chrome Users to access webpage using JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

Thanks to anyone who solves/helps solving this request. Sorry if this is an impossible/previously asked request. I searched for it, couldn't find it, so posted a question.

So, the issue is, that I want my page to be visible/usable only by Chrome users. And to other users, either display nothing when they try to access the page or Display a message stating: "Please use Google Chrome for Accessing this page"

It is preferable if the code is in JS, but jQuery or PHP will also work.

Thanks again.

Best JS code:

```
var isChromium = window.chrome,
    vendorName = window.navigator.vendor,
    isOpera = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("OPR") > -1,
    isIEedge = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
if(isChromium !== null && isChromium !== undefined && vendorName === "Google Inc." && isOpera == false && isIEedge == false) {
   // is Google chrome 
} else { 
   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");// not Google chrome 
}
```

Comment: Feature detection is better than user-agent detection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use navigator.userAgent to filter users:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1){

}
```